# webの要素をスクレイプする際のfindallの使い方

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

下記のHTML構造を持つURLから、td要素のa,b,cを取得して１行に並ぶように以下scriptを作成したのですが、どうしてもdまで取得してしまい、且つ出力されるものが乱れてしまいます。
div要素を限定するのかもしれませんが、理想とする出力を得る方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

■理想とする出力
URLのタイトル（1）、a,b,c,a',b',c',a'',b'',c'',a''',b''',c''',a'''',b'''',c'''',a''''',b''''',c'''''
URLのタイトル（2）、a,b,c,a',b',c',a'',b'',c'',a''',b''',c''',a'''',b'''',c'''',a''''',b''''',c'''''

---

**対象のHTML(例)**

```html
<div>
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>A</div><div>B</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>C</div><div>D</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        E
      </th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>a</div><div>b</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><span><a id="123" href="xxx.html" class="yyy">c</a></span></div>
        <div>d</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        e
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>a'</div><div>b'</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div><span><a id="456" href="xxx.html" class="yyy">c'</a></span></div>
        <div>d'</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        e'
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**スクリプト**

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

list = ["http://www.xxxxx", "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx"]

for target_url in list:
    html = urlopen(target_url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    # テーブルを指定
    try:
        title = bsObj.findAll("title")
        table = bsObj.findAll("table")[14] #ページ内で15番目のtable
        rows = table.findAll("tr")[1:6] # 1-5番目に記載しているものを取得
        # csvファイルに書き出す
        with open("ebooks_1.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8')  as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(title)
            csvRow = [] 
            for row in rows:
                for cell in row.findAll('td')[:2]:
                    csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
                writer.writerow(csvRow)
    except BaseException:
        with open("ebooks.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8')  as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(['エラー'])
```

Comment: `findAll('td')[:2]`を`findAll('div')[:3]`とか`findAll('div', limit=3)`にしてみるとか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
csvRow = [] を「for row in rows:」の中に移動させて、findAllをご教示いただいたものに変えたらdは取得しないで済みました。
しかしながら、各URLにつき1行に表示して繰り返していくというのは、依然として出来ません。

Comment: それは前回のQ&Aのように、`csvRow = []`を質問記事の元に戻して、`writer.writerow(csvRow)`のインデントを1段階浅く(`for row in rows:`と同じに)すれば良いのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。インデントを浅くしたらできました。
タイトルが同じ行になっていませんでしたが、単純に'''for row in rows:'''の前にcsvRow.append(title)を記載したら出来ました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参考までに、`findall()` ではなく CSS selector を利用すると以下の様に書くことができます。

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
csvRow = sum([
  [
    elm.getText() for elm in bsObj.select(
      f'table:nth-child(15) tr:nth-child({i}) td div'
    )[:3]
  ] for i in range(2, 6)
], [])

print(csvRow)

=>
['a', 'b', 'c', "a'", "b'", "c'"]
```

※ CSS selector で使用されるインデックス番号は 1 から始まります(1-base index)

Comment: ありがとうございます。css selectorでできずにfindall()を使ったので勉強になります。